# How to query multi values of enum field in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

mymodel.rb

```
enum status: { posted: 1, failed: 2, suspended: 3 }
```

mycontroller.rb

```
def filter_params
  params.fetch(:mymodel, {}).
  permit(
    :status => []
    )
end
```

And i have params like `mymodel[:status] => ["failed", "suspended"]`

How can i get all results by status is `failed` and `suspended`

Something like: `Mymodel.where(status: filter_params[:status])`

Thanks a lot!

And when a call:

```
@mymodel = Mymodel.new(filter_params)
```

I got this error:

```
'["failed", "suspended"]' is not a valid status
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When running a query, you need to supply the ordinal values for the enum attribute. So instead of strings like `'failed'` or `'suspended'`, you need to query using their integer values.

Luckily, you can access a hash to easily map all the statuses to integers from your `filter_params` hash:

```
values = Mymodel.statuses.values_at(*Array(filter_params[:status]))
```

With that you can run your query to get all records which have any of the filtered statuses:

```
Mymodel.where(status: values)
```

You don't want to scatter that piece of code all over the place though, so I recommend you'd implement this as a scope in your model:

```
class Mymodel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { posted: 1, failed: 2, suspended: 3 }

  scope :for_statuses, ->(values) do
    return all if values.blank?

    where(status: statuses.values_at(*Array(values)))
  end
end
```

Note that the `return all if values.blank?` line makes it possible to throw in `nil` or an empty array without breaking your query.

You can now easily query the records:

```
Mymodel.for_statuses(filter_params[:status])
```

Note that you cannot create a record which has multiple statuses. `enum` only restricts the values that can be assigned, but you can assign only one, otherwise you get the `not a valid status` error.

See [the Rails documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for more information about `enum`.

Comment: The your answer is very detailed. It's the thing I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

In **Rails 5** you can now pass a string array to the query, e.g:

```
Mymodel.where(status: ['failed', 'suspended'])
```

For earlier versions, just convert your array values to symbols:

```
statuses = filter_params[:status].map(&:to_sym)
Mymodel.where(status: statuses)
```